# web.groups["groupname"] cannot be found

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I cannot get group object using following syntax for "restricted readers" or "style resource reader"

for example this gives an error

```
   web.groups["restricted readers"] or

   web.sitegroups["restricted reader"]
```

throws "Group cannot be found" Exception

Comment: What settings of this group? Is anyone can see content of group or only group members?

Comment: yup I am admin user using with SystemAccount and can see group and contents

Answer (score 2):

How do you open the web? groups are normally stored in the rootweb, i.e.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you cant get the groups using that

1. The group isn't really there
2. Your user doesn't have access to the groups

In such cases try either delegate or...

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I open it using 
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        //...
    }
}

Comment: user is admin user . system account

Comment: OpenWeb may not be the rootweb

Comment: According to this post on SP stack exchange, you should never use RootWeb in a using statement? Now I'm confused. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17740/when-to-use-openweb-vs-rootweb